# Lubuntu/Ubuntu 16.04 Grey VNC

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, vnc

Can someone show me a fix for Lubuntu 16.04 running Gnome, I need to run VNC but I'm getting that stupid grey screen on connection to VNC server currently running this ./vnc/xstartup

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey 
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &

gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
```

I am getting a grey screen upon connection to the VNC server.

Answer (score 0):

I know old question but just in case if it helps someone:

I had same issue but i realized that I started with a new `xstartup`
and the file didn't have executable permission on it. So I gave the permission to the file and it was working fine

```
sudo chmod +x ~/.vnc/xstartup
vncserver -kill :1
vncserver :1
```